# JavaScript Redirection Loop

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm trying to implement a Facebook connect button to my website.
It's working, but it's written in JavaScript and I'd like to insert the information into the database (the tutorial I used is linked below.)
I'm trying to redirect the users from the index.php to index.php?name=xxx.
The name value is rendered with JavaScript so I can't simply just set a PHP variable, can I?
I've been told it's possible with $_GET so that's what I'm trying to achieve.
Using location.href/replace, both redirect to the same page over and over again...

This is the [tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/) I used.

I would like to store some information in the database, but I can't do it directly since it's JavaScript and not PHP.

Is there a solution/any other way?

Answer (score 0):

check if the name parameter is filled or not, and if it is, do not redirect

Comment: It does work.. it renders the name but when the page reloads, it obviously reads the code again and again...

Comment: allright, but this is the catch. If you have the name, you don't redirect anymore. can you post the code part we are talking about?